# Summarizing a joined report by an uncommon field

Tags: roll-up-summary, joined-reports

I am working on a joined report in which I want to summarize by a field that is available to one report block only. I have two blocks, i.e. two reports that I join. Help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a field that is only available to one report block, you can create a regular custom summary formula field for that block only.

If you are looking to create a cross-block custom summary formula field, to summarise across both blocks, you can't - the field needs to be common to both report blocks.

More information is available in the Salesforce help at:

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=reports_csf_joined_reports.htm&language=en_US